# Special characters must be escaped : [ > ].(spec-char-escape)

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

Special characters must be escaped : [ > ].(spec-char-escape)
I am facing this error when I am using js in ejs.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Model</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>All Products!</h1>
        <li>
            <% for(let products of product) {%> 
            <%= product.name %> 
            <%} %>
        </li>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible to share the value of `products`?